# Uploading BLOB to database using Catalyst::Request::Upload

Tags: perl, blob, catalyst, dbix-class

Among the methods with which the Catalyst upload object is blessed, none of them allows to retrieve the actual "blob" to store it directly as is in the database.

http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90114/lib/Catalyst/Request/Upload.pm

Is there any way to workaround this or should I just change the schema to store paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the 'slurp' method? It defaults to the :raw layer.

Comment: I think this is correct, but you should quote the doc and provide an example, or this should really be a comment.

Comment: I kind of missed the Slurp method. As @simbabque says, it is not a super detailed answer, but it did ring the bell so... thanks a lot :)

Comment: My answers are short and without much formatting when I'm on my smartphone.